# /questions/{id}/timeline throwing 500 instead of 404

Tags: bug, status-completed

**Kevin, you fixed this bug some time ago, would you like to tag it as status-complete?**

Sometime last week, this route stopped throwing 404 like the rest of my 'bad id' tests and started throwing 500.  It seems to be the odd man out.

```
Soapi.ApiException : A generic error has occurred on the server; developers have been notified.
StatusCode:InternalServerError
Url:http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/questions/2147483647/timeline
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this has been fixed for a while.

My bad.